# How find the value of $a$?

Tags: probability

let $X,Y$ are normally distributed random variables,and 
$E(X)=1.D(X)=2,E(Y)=3,D(Y)=4$,if such
$$P(X<0)=P(Y>a)$$
find the value $a$?

I think this problem have some methods.

Comment: And how is X and Y related?

Comment: What does $D$ stand for?

Comment: Assuming that $D$ stands for standard deviation or variance, you can convert $X$ and $Y$ into standard normal form, and use the fact that $P(Z<z) = P (Z > -z)$.

Comment: Assuming $D$ is std dev, I get $a = 5$ numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Thus

$P(X<0)=\Phi(\frac{0-E(X)}{\sqrt{D(X)}})=\Phi(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=\Phi(\frac{3-\sqrt2-E(Y)}{\sqrt{D(Y)}})=P(Y<3-\sqrt2)=P(Y>2E(Y)-（3-\sqrt2))=P(Y>3+\sqrt2)$

where $\Phi(x)$ is cdf of standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Given $X \sim N(1, 2)$ and $Y \sim N(3, 4)$, let $Z \sim N(0, 1)$

$P(X < 0) = P(Z < -\frac{1}{2}) = P(Z > \frac{1}{2})$ and $P(Y > a) = P(Z > \frac{a-3}{4})$

So comparing arguments, $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{a-3}{4}$ or $a = 5$.